# How to find any trigonometric ratio of any angle?

Tags: trigonometry

Let's consider some angles viz. 1253°, 1569° etc. , so how can I find the sine, cosine, tangent, cotangent, secant, cosecant of these angles ? Is there any specific formula to do that or do I have to apply different processes to achieve the values for different angles ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find the coterminal angle in the first rotation (e.g. $1253^\circ$ is coterminal with $1253^\circ-3(360^\circ)=173^\circ)$ and find the ratios of that angle instead.

Comment: Use a calculator? Or you can use the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions) yourself...

Comment: Thats ok but, my question is something, like how to find the trigonometric ratios of any angles, e.g. 173°, 195°, 253°, 12009°, (-373°), anything......

Comment: Are you looking for a way to express these ratios as exact values?  Otherwise, you can just use a calculator.

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch, I can use a calculator, but I really want to know how does the calculator solves it !!!

Comment: @Andrew Chin Yes !!!

Comment: @ArcanadianArc The (numerical) calculator will add up the first terms of the Taylor series. In general, for an angle $\alpha$, $\sin(\alpha), \cos(\alpha),\dots$ are the best closed forms you can get

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch Thank You

Comment: There are [certain angles](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html) that you could find exact values for.  Otherwise, you're rather out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the procedure : make the euclidean division of your angle by 360, say the rest of that division is $r$.

Now, compute the sine, cosine, tangent, cotangent, secant, cosecant of $r$ : it is the sine, cosine, tangent, cotangent, secant, cosecant (respectively) of your angle.